# C - Int não transformando em float

Tags: c

Por que meu codigo não transforma o int em float e retorna um resultado errado? Como posso arrumar?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

float a,a2,kg_t;
int kg_moran,kg_maca;

printf("\nInsira a quantidade de quilos de morango a serem compradas: ");
scanf("%i", &kg_moran);

printf("Insira a quantidade de quilos de maçãs a serem compradas: ");
scanf("%i", &kg_maca);

if (kg_moran <=5){
    a = (float) kg_moran * 2.50;

}else if(kg_moran > 5){
    a = (float) kg_moran * 2.20;

}else if(kg_maca <=5){
    a2 = (float) kg_maca * 1.80;

}else if(kg_maca > 5){
    a2 = (float) kg_maca * 1.50;
}

kg_t = a + a2;

printf("Sua compra foi de %0.2f reais!\n\n", kg_t);

printf("%0.2f\n", a);
printf("%0.2f\n", a2);
```

}

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Substitua

```
}else if(kg_maca <=5){
```

por

```
}
if(kg_maca <=5){
```

Porque não faz sentido você misturar esses 2 testes envolvendo kg de morangos e kg de maçãs. Do jeito que você fez, ele nunca vai fazer os testes para kg_macas porque sempre 1 dos testes feitos para kg_moran vai dar verdadeiro.

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado!